# NonRecursive PostOrder Binary Tree Traversal using parallel stacks

Tags: java, traversal, postorder

I'm suppose to take this pseucode-ish algorithm of a nonrecursive postorder binary tree traversal and actually implement it into code. Essentially i'm suppose to create two parallel stacks, one to save the references to the nodes, and one to save the integer value 1 or 2, to tell whether the left or right subtree have been visited. I created the algorithm based off what they gave me but for some reason its only printing some of the numbers and not in the correct order, i feel like i interpreted it like it should be but its just now working, any help would be nice.

Heres what they want me to do:

```
1.create stack(s)
2. current = root;
3.v = 0;
4. if (current is null)
    the binary tree is empty
5. if (current is not null)
    a. push current onto stack;
    b. push 1 onto stack;
    c. current = current.lLink;
6. while (stack is not empty)
      if (current is not null and v is 0)
      {
          push current and 1 onto stack;
          current = current.lLink
      }
      else
      {
          pop stack into current and v;
          if ( v == 1)
          {
              push current and 2 onto stack;
              current = current.rLink;
              v = 0;
          }
          else
              visit current;
      }
```

And here is my implementation of it:

```
public void nonRecursivePostTraversal()
{
    LinkedStackClass<BinaryTreeNode<T> > stack
    = new LinkedStackClass<BinaryTreeNode<T> >();//create stack

    //create parallel stack of integers
    LinkedStackClass<Integer> stackInt = new LinkedStackClass<Integer>();

    BinaryTreeNode<T> current;
    current = root;

    Integer v = 0;

    if (current == null)
        stack = null;

    if   (current != null)
    {
        stack.push(current);
        v = 1;
        stackInt.push(v);
        current = current.lLink;
    }


    while (!stack.isEmptyStack())
        if (current != null && v == 0)
        {
            stack.push(current);
            v = 1;
            stackInt.push(v);
            current = current.lLink;

        }
        else
        {
            current = (BinaryTreeNode<T>) stack.peek();
            stack.pop();
            v = (Integer) stackInt.peek();
            stackInt.pop();
            if (v == 1)
            {
                stack.push(current);
                v = 2;
                stackInt.push(v);
                current = current.rLink;
                v = 0;
            }
            else
                System.out.print(current.info + " ");
        }

}//end alg
```

Comment: What isn't working? What do you expect it to do? What does it do? Are you getting an exception? If so, what is it and on what line?

Comment: its suppose to traverse the binary tree printing out each node in postOrder. When i use it in a test method, it only prints out some of the numbers, and not in the correct order.I think the problem is where I'm putting the peek() methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void nonRecursivePostOrder(BinaryTreeNode root){


    Stack<BinaryTreeNode> stack = new Stack<BinaryTreeNode>();
    List<BinaryTreeNode> returnNodes = new LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode>();


      while (true) {
          if (root != null) {

              if (returnNodes.contains(root)) {
                  returnNodes.add(stack.pop());
                  root = null;
              } else {
                  stack.push(root);
                  root = root.getLeft();
              }

          } else {
              if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                  break;
              } else if (stack.peek().getRight() == null) {
                  root = stack.pop();
                  returnNodes.add(root);
                  if (root == stack.peek().getRight()) {
                      returnNodes.add(stack.pop());
                  }
              }

              if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                  root = stack.peek().getRight();
              } else {
                  root = null;
              }
          }
      }

      for(BinaryTreeNode node : returnNodes)
          System.out.print(node.getData()+" ");

}
```

Comment: put more detail about your answer! avoid putting just the code